# What are the values for "drop-out mode" in freetype?

Tags: c, freetype, opentype

I'm trying to figure out all the values for the fields of [FT_Outline](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-outline_processing.html#ft_outline).  One of those fields in a flag with size of char, in the documentation it states:

> If bit 2 is set, bits 5-7 contain the drop-out mode (as defined in the OpenType specification; the value is the same as the argument to the ‘SCANMODE’ instruction).

But I cannot find where these values are actually defined.  I see drop out control [mode in opentype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/tt_instructions#scan-conversion-control), but the number of bits requires to store that is way more than 3, and I've found no mention of this "SCANMODE" instruction, google turns up nothing.

Comment: These are freetype-specific values, not OpenType values. If the docs are unclear, request the docs be clarified on the [freetype issue tracker](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/groups/freetype/-/issues)?